# Alternate cgi scripts on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling with a power button that is supposed to run two different cgi scripts when it is pressed.

I have some code like so (I've truncated the code between`<main>` tags) :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="site">
<main>
<button href="#" class="buttonb" onclick="onoff()"><img class="on-button" src="images/power.png" alt="ON"></button>
</main>
<script>
var isOn=false;
function onoff()
{
  if(isOn)
{
  window.location.href="/cgi-bin/turnon.pl";
  var isOn=true;
}else
{
  window.location.href="/cgi-bin/turnoff.pl";
  var isOn=false;
}
}
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

I have some css formatting things so it looks better too.

For some reason no matter what I do I can only get the else option to run on every button push. ie. it only runs the off script.  The individual scripts do what is intended when run from the console.

Can someone shed some light on what is going on or maybe suggest another way of achieving the same thing?  I'm a newbie to this stuff if that makes a difference

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a local variable `isOn` instead of setting the value of the global variable `isOn`.

The logic is also incorrect where `isOn` is defined as `false` initially

```html
<button href="" class="buttonb" onclick="onoff()"><img class="on-button" src="" alt="ON"></button>
<script>
  var isOn = false;

  function onoff() {
    if (!isOn) {
      isOn = true;
      console.log(isOn)
    } else {
      isOn = false;
      console.log(isOn)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that - some progress :) it seems that I need to double click to toggle the second time round which is a bit odd.  any ideas

Comment: @SteveW Do not need to double click, here. Each click toggles `Boolean` value, as demonstrated at stacksnippets

Comment: I've got to be missing something?  I can't get it to switch between the two scripts. `code`var isOn = false;    
function onoff(){
  if(!isOn) { 
    isOn=true;
    console.log(!isOn);
    window.location.href="/cgi-bin/ToshibaACPWROFF.pl";
   } else {
    isOn=false;
    console.log(isOn);
    window.location.href="/cgi-bin/ToshibaACPWRON.pl";
  }
 }`code`  The two perl scripts work fine on their own buttons

Comment: and double clicking still works if I wait a few seconds?

Comment: If you are setting `window.location.href` then the variable will be reset at each click. See [Global Variable usage on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload)

Comment: Genius!  local.storage seems to do exactly what is needed.